# Problems with uploading images with move_uploaded_file in external server

Tags: php, mysql, image

Have this page, where user can upload files from admin panel, everything worked well in wamp server localhost. 
  Uploaded all the files to external host server and made new MySQL tables with same names, same field-name´s etc.

Now if I upload images, they do not appear, only an empty box with "thumbnail" written in it. It can be seen here: http://www.heiberg.ee/test/gallery.php

But when I try to upload some of these images which were uploaded before with wampserver and therefore are already in external server "images"-folder (I downloaded files to external host server with images in image folder) - they will appear.

As I look into the mysql table in external server - the images info appears in the table as it should be, this side works. But when I search the actual file from my external hosts servers image folder - I can´t fint the ones I insert for testing.

code: 
from insert_images.php (included php-file, which inserts data):

```
<?php include("includes/connect.php"); 

   if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

       $post_title = $_POST['title'];
       $post_keywords = $_POST['keywords'];
       $post_content = $_POST['content'];
       $post_image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
       $image_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];


   if($post_image=='') {

     echo "<script>alert('UNUSTASID PILDI LISADA!')</script>";   
     exit();  

     }    
       else {

         move_uploaded_file($image_tmp,"../images/$post_image");

         $insert_query = "INSERT INTO pics(pic_image,pic_title,pic_keywords,
         pic_text) values('$post_image','$post_title','$post_keywords'
         ,'$post_content')";

          if(mysqli_query($con,$insert_query)) {

              echo "<center><h3>PILDI LISAMINE &Otilde;NNESTUS!</h3>      </center>";
              }

         }

     }

  ?>
```

from gallerycontent.php (included php-file which echoes data to the page dynamically):

```
<script>
function newPopup(url) {
    popupWindow = window.open(
        url,'popUpWindow','height=800,width=1200,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')
}
</script>

<div id="content-spacegallery"></div>



   <?php 
   include('config/connect.php');

   $select_query = "SELECT * FROM pics";

   $run_query = mysqli_query($con, $select_query);

      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query)) {

          $picid = $row['pic_id'];
          $picimage = $row['pic_image'];
          $pictitle = $row['pic_title'];
          $pickeywords = $row['pic_keywords'];
          $piccontent = substr($row['pic_text'],0,400);


      ?>  



 <div class="product-container">


   <div class="image-area">
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick=newPopup("images/<?php echo $picimage; ?>"); class="zoom"><img src="images/<?php echo $picimage; ?>" class="tootepilt" alt="thumbnail"/></a>
   <!--    <p class="tootenimi"><?php echo $pictitle ?></p>
   <p class="tootekirjeldus"><?php echo $piccontent ?></p> -->

     </div> <!-- end image-area -->
 </div> <!-- end product-container -->




 <?php } ?>

 <div id="content-space2"></div>
```

Comment: Do you have write access in the folder?

Comment: Have you check the permission of that folder in which you are trying to upload image ? Your folder must have write permission.

Comment: how can I check that permission?